# Using map in scheme

Tags: dictionary, scheme

I've created a procedure called movies-satisfying:

```
(define movies-satisfying          
    (lambda (movies pred selector)
      (map (pred movies))))
```

This is how I call the procedure.

```
(movies-satisfying our-movie-database
               (lambda (movie)
                 (= (movie-year-made movie) 1974))
               movie-title)
```

the movie title = car. 
our-movie-database is a database of movies.

Which returns a lot of information about the movie from a database starting with movie title, director, date it was made, and actors. How do I return just the movie title instead of the entire list?

This is what currently gets returned:

```
 (((amarcord)
  (federico fellini)
  1974
  ((magali noel) (bruno zanin) (pupella maggio) (armando drancia)))
```

Comment: That code can't be working. The way you're calling `map` is wrong: it expects _two_ arguments. What is `selector` and why isn't being used? are you sure you didn't intend to use `filter` instead of `map`? and you should post an actual example of `our-movie-database`, otherwise we won't be able to reproduce the problem. Edit the question and make sure that the code posted compiles and runs by itself, without missing dependencies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to give a perfect answer without knowing more of the code (as stated in my comment), but I can outline the answer, the trick is to make two passes - of course, assuming that both the predicate and the selector are correctly defined. For example, a search in particular will look like this:

```
(map (lambda (movie) ; 2nd pass: obtain the names of the movies returned by 1st pass
       (movie-title movie))
     (filter (lambda (movie) ; 1st pass: obtain only the movies of a given year
               (= (movie-year-made movie) 1974))
             our-movie-database))
```

To write the above as a parameterizable function, just pass the `lambdas` along, as parameters:

```
(define movies-satisfying          
  (lambda (movies pred selector)
    (map selector (filter pred movies))))
```

Also be aware that `filter` must be used to find matches for a given predicate, `map` will always return a list of the same size of the original input list.

Comment: Thank you very much for the outline, it fixed my problem! Sorry about being brief, you are incredibly helpful!

Comment: @user2872793 my pleasure! you'll get better, faster answers if you take the time to write the question as an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) - Short, Self Contained, Compilable Example